# IIS 8 & Plesk web.config to enable parent paths and error reporting

Tags: web-config, plesk, iis-8

I'm moving a classic ASP site from shared hosting IIS 6 site to shared IIS 8 host that uses Plesk, so the only control of IIS is via a few settings in Plesk, or web.config.

Plesk has settings to enable ASP support (which I have done) and ASP.NET support (tried enabled and disabled, but this is classic ASP so should not matter).

I have been unable to get enableParentPaths to work.  I also cannot get detailed errors displayed.  My initial web.config probably has stuff only relevant to ASP.NET, but I have been trying all sorts of suggestions from forums.  I would love to simplify.  I just want classic ASP with ParentPaths and (temporarily) detailed error reporting.

UPDATE.  GoDaddy Tech Support suggested a simpler web.config that allowed me to see detailed errors.  They do not know how to enable Parent Paths, but those are not always a good idea and it was easy enough to manually change /../../filename to a full path, so the migration to IIS 8 with Plesk is complete.

Here is the web.config that allows me to see detailed errors during debugging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This was the version that did not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<location path="mydomain.com" overrideMode="Allow">  
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />      
    <asp enableParentPaths="true" appAllowDebugging="true" scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true">
        <session keepSessionIdSecure="false" />
    </asp>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to enable parent paths simply by using the web.config, but I did find instructions on how to enable parent paths in the Plesk control panel:

In the new Plesk panel:

-- go to VIrtual Directories

-- click on Directory Properties

-- check the box "Enable Parent Paths", then save.