# ASP classic include files in parent directory with plesk on godaddy

Tags: asp-classic, plesk

I know that you need to enable parent paths in order to include files in a parent directory, however I have no way of enabling this property on godaddy's plesk hosting.  Is there any way around this or do I just need to upload the include files into each and every directory on my site.

The idea of the include files was that I would have less that needed maintaining, and if I need to upload them into every folder then I certainly don't have less to maintain.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Already been asked - [IIS 8 & Plesk web.config to enable parent paths and error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25951524/692942)

Comment: @Lankymart: (1) there's no answer to that question, so it's not a terribly useful link. (2) the question-as-edited is no longer really about enabling parent paths.

Comment: @Martha really? *"
UPDATE. GoDaddy Tech Support suggested a simpler web.config that allowed me to see detailed errors. **They do not know how to enable Parent Paths, but those are not always a good idea and it was easy enough to manually change /../../filename to a full path**, so the migration to IIS 8 with Plesk is complete."*

Comment: @Lankymart - You are correct that someone else ran into a problem that has a similar cause (Plesk on Godaddy), however they have a different problem that requires a different solution.  I actually read that question before posting mine, I state in my question that I have no way of enabling parent paths because I had already read that other post.  I was simply looking for a work around to the problem.  Martha provided me with a work around that works perfectly.

Comment: If you had read that question first, surely you realised that using the full path instead of `../../` us exactly the same as *"it was easy enough to manually change /../../filename to a full path"* from that question, it's not just similar it's the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* include files that are "higher up" in the folder hierarchy, you just can't use the `file="../../"` syntax. Instead, use "virtual" instead of "file" and specify the full path relative to the site's root:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/path/to/includes/filename.inc" -->
```

This has the added advantage of always being the same path, regardless of where you're including it, so you can copy & paste to your heart's content.

Of course, this will require editing every page that has includes in it, but since you were going to do that anyway, I gather this is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to allow parent path in plesk shared hosting, for example: godaddy

1. Go to **Virtual Directories**
2. Find **Directory Properties** under Tools section, click on it
3. Tick **Allow to use parent paths** checkbox under Application settings section

Hope this helps.